# How to find a div inside of a div and add css by using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is my js fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/wo80c90n/

I want a jquery where if "agenda" class is not found inside of "inner-content" class then the "form" class width should be 100% instead of 50%

HTML-

```css
.inner-content{
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
        display: inline-block;
        overflow: hidden;
        background;#000;
      }
      .form, .agenda{
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        width: 50%; 
        height: 100%;
        text-align:center;
      }
      .form{ background:#ddd;}
      .agenda{ background:#999;}
```

```html
<div class="inner-content">
        <div class="agenda">
          sadsadsad
        </div>
        <div class="form">
          abcd
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried but that looks messy that's why i didn't add it

Comment: Messy is fine...that's what we're here for to, correct your code...if we can.

Comment: its okay you can add that in your Fiddle if you dont want to post it here but dont ask at SO to write code for you.

Comment: I update it now.. If i can be so expert in Jquery the there is no point to ask here to you genious guys

Answer (score 2):

Simply search for the `.agenda` inside and if not there change the css.

```
if( !$(".inner-content .agenda").length ) {
    $(".inner-content .form").css("width", "100%");
}
```

**[Working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/wo80c90n/3/)**

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you don't need javscript for that, just use the CSS cascade.

However, this is highly fragile and structure dependant.

```
.form {
  width: 100%;
}
.agenda + .form {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```css
.inner-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.form,
.agenda {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.form {
  background: #ddd;
}
.agenda {
  background: #999;
}
.form {
  width: 100%;
}
.agenda + .form {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner-content">
  <div class="agenda">
    Agenda
  </div>
  <div class="form">
    Form
  </div>
</div>

<div class="inner-content">
  <div class="form">
    Form
  </div>
</div>
```

Or **Flexbox**

```
  .form, .agenda{
    flex:1;
    text-align:center;
  }
```

```css
.inner-content {
  height: 100px;
  background;
  #000;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.form,
.agenda {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
.form {
  background: #ddd;
}
.agenda {
  background: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner-content">
  <div class="agenda">
    sadsadsad
  </div>
  <div class="form">
    abcd
  </div>
</div>

<div class="inner-content">
  <div class="form">
    abcd
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this jQuery Code:

```
if(!$('.agenda').length){
    $('.form').width('100%');
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/wo80c90n/6/

But you can fix this issue with some css code:

```
.inner-content{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    display: table;
    overflow: hidden;
    background;#000;
    table-layout: fixed;
  }
  .form, .agenda{
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    text-align:center;
  }
  .form{ background:#ddd;}
  .agenda{ background:#999;}
```

Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/wo80c90n/8/

Comment: Can we add a border with 100% width, Is it possible??

Comment: I mean border in left side by jquery?

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant by that. @moiduldargahi

Comment: Its ok Mohammad I did it my own

Comment: Yeah you can use jQuery like this: `if(!$('.agenda').length){
 $('.form').css({'width' : '100%', 'border-left' : '1px solid #ddd'});
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
 if(!$('.inner-content').is('.agenda')) {
//code here
}
});
```

that should work.

`.is()` will check the content of jQuery object(element). In the above example we have checked whether the class has another class as a child. More correctly, because of negative (not) operator `!.is()`, we have checked if the class **doesn't** have another class as a child. `.is()` doesn't create objects, it only checks the contents.

Please note that `.is()` is not opposite of `.not()`. While `.not()` is a filtering method and it creates an object, the `.is()` doesn't.

`.not()` is the opposite of `.filter()`.

not operator - `!.is()` is the opposite of `.is()`.

I have just seen that I answered more than asked here. Sorry, I get carried away when talking about Javascript.

Comment: can you elaborate, what this code does. It's not clear from this code snippet, how this helps answering the question?

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Edited per request.

Answer (score 0):

A very easy and nice way will be to use CSS as

> Paulie_D suggested

But if you need/want to use jQuery I'll use :not(), find() or hasclass()

```
$('.inner-content div:first-child:not(.agenda)').css('width', '100%')
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wo80c90n/12/

Answer (score -1):

```css
.inner-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.form,
.agenda {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.form {
  background: #ddd;
}
.agenda {
  background: #999;
}
.form {
  width: 100%;
}
.agenda + .form {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner-content">
  <div class="agenda">
    Agenda
  </div>
  <div class="form">
    Form
  </div>
</div>

<div class="inner-content">
  <div class="form">
    Form
  </div>
</div>
```